# What is the correct method of making json requests and storing values while looping through an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I would like to loop through an array of addresses so I can request their respective geolocations using the google maps geocode api.  I'm having trouble pushing the results (lat/long coordinates) into an array.  It seems like the console.log function below is firing before the code above it is finished executing.

I would appreciate it if someone could point this javascript noob in the right direction.

```
    function getCoords() {
      $.each(addressList, function(index, val) {
        $.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + val + '&key=apikey').done(function(data){
          coordsList.push(data.results[0].geometry.location);
        });
      });
      console.log(coordsList);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You're mixing synchronous and asynchronous code. As you suspected, your `console.log` is firing before the requests have completed.

jQuery's deferred objects are good for this sort of thing - i.e. do something when a bunch of asynchronous code has completed.

```
var reqs = []; //set up a container to log our async requests to Google
$.each(addressList, function(index, val) {
    reqs.push($.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + val + '&key=apikey').done(function(data){
        coordsList.push(data.results[0].geometry.location);
    }));
});

//when ALL async requests have completed, console.log.
$.when.apply(this, reqs).done(function() { console.log(coordsList); });
```

The need for `apply()` is a little outside the scope of this question if you're a JS noob, but essentially it's a way of passing an array to a function that expects not an array but separate arguments. `$.when()` expects requests passed as separate arguments, i.e. `$.when(req1, req2, ...)` but our requests are in an array; `apply()` gets round this. [Here's more on apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question.  I tried running the code that you provided after adding my apikey, however it doesn't seem to work.  I'm not getting anything in the console, not even an empty array.  I see the data when I put the log function inside the .each loop though.

Comment: a `var coordsList=[];` is needed at the top of your script. Same way you did for the `reqs`.

Comment: It worked when I changed it to this: `$.when.apply($, reqs).done(function() {console.log(coordsList);});`

Comment: Yeap, my mistake. Glad you got there in the end.